# Map a set of groups to a set of relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of IDs and groups that those IDs belong to. It looks like this-

```
ID    Group
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     A
10    A
11    A
12    A    
13    A
14    A
15    A
20    A
1     B
2     B
3     B
5     B
6     B
13    B
17    B
18    B
19    B
20    B
7     C
8     C
9     C
10    C
11    C
12    C
16    C
18    C
19    C
```

I'd like to do two things

1. Create a row for every relationship and give it an ID
2. Create a Relatoinship Group that corresponds to all of the users who are in the same group with a given user

This is what I'd like my output to look like-

```
Relational Group    Relationship    from_ID     to_ID   group
Z                    111                  1         2       A
Z                    112                  1         3       A                         
Z                    113                  1         4       A
Z                    114                  1        10       A
Z                    115                  1        11       A
Z                    116                  1        12       A
Z                    117                  1        13       A
Z                    118                  1        14       A
Z                    119                  1        15       A
Z                    120                  1         2       B
Z                    121                  1         3       B
Z                    122                  1         5       B
Z                    123                  1         6       B
Z                    124                  1        13       B
Z                    125                  1        17       B
Z                    126                  1        18       B
Z                    127                  1        19       B
Z                    128                  1        20       B
X                    129                  2         3       A
X                    130                  2         4       A
..                    ..                 ..        ..      ..
```

I've tried to solve this by self joining, but I run into a trap where I'm trying to self join against every unique ID and that's not working

Comment: You should explain the logic behind your tasks #1 & #2. What's the definition of *relationship*?

Comment: What you want to do is not clear.  Perhaps a smaller set of data would help.

Comment: A relationship is a per-group tie between one ID and another ID. A relationship group is the set of all the ties originating from a single vertice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerating the relationships seems to just be a self join:

```
select l1.group, l1.id as from_id, l2.id as to_id,
       row_number() over (order by l1.group, l1.id, l2.id)
from list l1 join
     list l2
     on l1.group = l2.group and l1.id = l2.id;
```

The "relational group" then appears to be keeping track of the `from_id`, so `dense_rank()` can generate this:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by l1.id) as relational_group,
       l1.group, l1.id as from_id, l2.id as to_id,
       row_number() over (order by l1.group, l1.id, l2.id)
from list l1 join
     list l2
     on l1.group = l2.group and l1.id = l2.id;
```

Comment: What's the difference between `rank` and `dense_rank`

Comment: @tadon11Aaa . . . `rank()` skips numbers, so it would product 1,1,1,4.  `dense_rank()` does not skip numbers, so it would produce 1,1,1,2.

Comment: Does that means it's the same as row_number?

Comment: @tadon11Aaa . . . All three are there the same if there are no duplicates.  If there are duplicates, they are generally different, although there are some edge cases where `rank()` and `dense_rank()` are the same.